# IONIC 2 Native Push Notification Neither Redirecting nor showing

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2

Previously I was using Ionic cloud **PUSH** and everything was working fine. Now I want to manage it from my server.

I already have had installed **phonegap-plugin-push** with sender ID as the same was being used by IONIC cloud push.

Imported the Native PUSH:

```
import { StatusBar, Splashscreen, GoogleAnalytics, Push } from 'ionic-native'; // Native Push
```

Below is how I have initiated PUSH:

```
let push = Push.init({
      android: {
        icon: "blicon",
        iconColor: "#AE2829",
        senderID: Config.fcmSenderID
      },
      ios: {
        alert: "true",
        badge: "true",
        sound: "true"
      },
      windows: {}
});
```

Below is how Device token is getting saved to server, working fine:-

```
push.on('registration', (data) => {

    // SAVE TO Server
        this.device_details.device_token = data.registrationId; 
        var form = new FormData();
        form.append("user_device_token", this.device_details.device_token);
        form.append("user_device_type", this.device_details.device_type);
        //console.log(form);
        this.webService.saveToken(form)
        .subscribe(response => {
           console.log(response.message);
        }, error => {
           console.log("Oooops!" + error);
        });
    // SAVE TO Server
});
```

Everything is working as supposed so far and I am able to receive push notification in my device, now it comes to handle the receieved push parameter.

```
push.on('notification', function(data) {
    if(data.additionalData.foreground == false) {
        this.nav.push(DetailPage, {id: data.additionalData.pageid});
    } else {
        let confirm = this.alertCtrl.create({
          title: data.title,
          message: data.message,
          buttons: [
            {
              text: 'Check Later',
              role: 'cancel'
            },
            {
              text: 'Check Now',
              handler: () => {
                if(data.additionalData.postid !== undefined) {
                    this.nav.push(DetailPage, {id: data.additionalData.pageid});                
                } 
              }
            }
          ]
        });
        confirm.present();
    }
```

Whenever I try to use ALERT command it pop'ups every value that I send with payload but nothing else happens.

It do not push to the detail page with ID parameter and do not even show the Alertcontrol box.

Please help me resolving this issue.

Thanks Sanny

Comment: Please use the below URL https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44605734/how-to-send-push-notification-with-angularjs-and-cordova-fcm/44605950#44605950

Answer (score 0):

Setting up Ionic 2 App to generate device token
            For Android, follow FCM setup instructions. It will give you SERVER_KEY and SENDER_ID. SERVER_KEY is used by server to send push notification and SENDER_ID is used by device to generate device token. For iOS, nothing required to generate device token.

```
        Replace YOUR_SENDER_ID in config.xml with above SENDER_ID


        <plugin name="phonegap-plugin-push" spec="1.8.2">    
        <variable name="SENDER_ID" value="YOUR_SENDER_ID"/>   
        </plugin>

        Add device token generation code in your main app constructor like below and replace YOUR_SENDER_ID in Push.init() method with above SENDER_ID


        import {Component, ViewChild} from "@angular/core";
        import {AlertController, Nav, Platform} from "ionic-angular";
        import {StatusBar} from "@ionic-native/status-bar";
        import {SplashScreen} from "@ionic-native/splash-screen";
        import {Push, PushObject, PushOptions} from "@ionic-native/push";
        import {TabsPage} from "../pages/tabs/tabs";
        import {DetailsPage} from "../pages/details/details";

        @Component({
        template: '<ion-nav [root]="rootPage"></ion-nav>'
        })
        export class Ionic2PushApp {
        @ViewChild(Nav) nav: Nav;
        rootPage: any;

        constructor(public platform: Platform,
                    public statusBar: StatusBar,
                    public splashScreen: SplashScreen,
                    public push: Push,
                    public alertCtrl: AlertController) {
            this.rootPage = TabsPage;
            platform.ready().then(() => {
            this.statusBar.styleDefault();
            this.splashScreen.hide();
            this.initPushNotification();
            });
        }

        initPushNotification() {
            if (!this.platform.is('cordova')) {
            console.warn("Push notifications not initialized. Cordova is not available - Run in physical device");
            return;
            }
            const options: PushOptions = {
            android: {
                senderID: "YOUR_SENDER_ID"
            },
            ios: {
                alert: "true",
                badge: false,
                sound: "true"
            },
            windows: {}
            };
            const pushObject: PushObject = this.push.init(options);

            pushObject.on('registration').subscribe((data: any) => {
            console.log("device token ->", data.registrationId);
            //TODO - send device token to server
            });

            pushObject.on('notification').subscribe((data: any) => {
            console.log('message', data.message);
            //if user using app and push notification comes
            if (data.additionalData.foreground) {
                // if application open, show popup
                let confirmAlert = this.alertCtrl.create({
                title: 'New Notification',
                message: data.message,
                buttons: [{
                    text: 'Ignore',
                    role: 'cancel'
                }, {
                    text: 'View',
                    handler: () => {
                    //TODO: Your logic here
                    this.nav.push(DetailsPage, {message: data.message});
                    }
                }]
                });
                confirmAlert.present();
            } else {
                //if user NOT using app and push notification comes
                //TODO: Your logic on click of push notification directly
                this.nav.push(DetailsPage, {message: data.message});
                console.log("Push notification clicked");
            }
            });

            pushObject.on('error').subscribe(error => console.error('Error with Push plugin', error));
        }
        }
```